# How to remove part of a string with preg_replace?

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace

Hi I have to remove a part of a string. The code is as follow:-

```
$string = "19Apr2016";
$search = '_'.$string;

$v1 = "DA6220_19Apr2016";
$v1 = preg_replace("([$search])", "", $v1);
echo $v1 ;
```

The following code only returns D as output. I want remove _19Apr2016 from the string. Please point out what i am doing wrong.

Comment: What part of the string DA6220_19Apr2016 you want to remove ?

Comment: try this: `preg_replace("/$search/", "", $v1);`

Comment: don't wrap your regex with square brackets

Comment: @FrayneKonok Thank you it worked

Answer (score 1):

Replace,

```
preg_replace("([$search])", "", $v1);
```

with,

```
preg_replace("/$search/", "", $v1);
```

Answer (score 0):

`[$search]` is a character class that means one of character in the list `_,1,9,A,p,r,2,0,1,6`, when you replace in the string `$v1 = "DA6220_19Apr2016"` every character that is in the list, you get `D`, the only character that is not in the list.

You want to use:

```
$v1 = preg_replace("($search)", "", $v1);
```

or, using more common regex delimiter:

```
$v1 = preg_replace("/$search/", "", $v1);
```